# date stored in sqlite table as date('15:20:16',strftime('%H:%M:%S')).Is it correct?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
receivedDate="25022013";
receivedTime="150526";

receivedTime=receivedTime.trim();
String HH = receivedTime.substring(0, 2);
String MM = receivedTime.substring(2, 4);
String SS = receivedTime.substring(4, 6);

receivedTime="date('"+HH+":"+MM+":"+SS+"',strftime('%H:%M:%S'))";

receivedDate=receivedDate.trim();
String dd = receivedDate.substring(0, 2);
String mm = receivedDate.substring(2, 4);
String yyyy = "20"+receivedDate.substring(4,6);

receivedDate="date('"+yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd+"',strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))";

ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(DBConstants.TIME,receivedTime);
values.put(DBConstants.DATE, receivedDate);

masterDataDB.insert(DBConstants.MASTER_DATA_TABLE, null, values);
```

This date and time are inserted in TEXT type fields. When i see the store data on Sqlite browser,it store like below,

In Time field-> **date('15:20:16',strftime('%H:%M:%S'))**

In Date field-> **date('2013-02-14',strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))**

is it correctly stored? If i select date and time using date function it will return date properly?

Comment: As you are changing the date format so it will store the date in database according the format which you have set.

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve the date from database and checked the format'?

Comment: i have confused...SQLite3 document said use any type like TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER.But they didnt give any sample

Comment: I simple stored as 15:20:16.Then when using select query used date().it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL functions you are building aren't executed but stored as strings. You can store date as formatted string or long (time since unix epoch).

In other words, don't store the string `date('15:20:16',strftime('%H:%M:%S'))`, but simply `15:20:16`.

Comment: Thank You CL..It works fine.I tested it.Put your answer.I will accept

Answer (score 0):

You should store it as a long value in the database and then manipulate it in the code using the proper classes for it (Calendar, Date, DateFormat)